# React : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code for Home.js and it is giving me an error regarding properties of undefined (reading 'error'). Can please anyone suggest a solution for this?

Here is the code in Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import  {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import {getProducts} from "./helper.js/coreapicalls"

function Home() {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const loadAllProducts = () => {
        getProducts()
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
            setError(data.error);
            console.log(error);
            } else {
            setProducts(data);
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadAllProducts();
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home component</h1>
            <div className = "row">
                {products.map((product , index)=>{
                    return(
                        <div key = {index}>
                            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

×
**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')**

```
  10 | const loadAllProducts = () => {
  11 |     getProducts()
  12 |     .then((data) => {
> 13 |         if (data.error) {
     | ^  14 |         setError(data.error);
  15 |         console.log(error);
  16 |         } else {
```

Comment: I think this is because `data` doesn't have any error attribute

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` after line number 12?
 Seems like it does not have an attribute called `error`

Comment: You can write it like: `if (data?.error)` which is equal to `if (data && data.error)`

Answer (score -1):

your `data` is probably undefined, hence reading `error` property on an `undefined` fails on line 13 `if (data.error)`